# Console session stuck ESXi unsuported mode

Tags: vmware-esxi

I was editing the   /etc/inetd.conf    file in VI to enable SSH and when I believed to have saved it. I entered cat and pressed enter accidently. Now I seem to be stuck in a black screen where I can enter characters but can't exit from it. How would I go on my way to get back to the normal console without rebooting the ESXi.

Thanks

Comment: I seem to recall that the blank screen is just not echoing characters to the screen, but the commands are being entered. Are you able to switch consoles with the alt-f<number> keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `ctrl-c`.  Cat without any parameters will direct stdin (your keyboard input) to stdout (your screen) until it is interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

As ktower says, `Ctrl+C` should get you out of `cat`, if you're stuck in that.

If you want to get back to the normal ESXi interface, try `Alt+F2` (could be a different number, if that doesn't work, try the other F keys).